# Is this "if e is a pack, then get a template name, otherwise get a variable name" valid or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I have tried to construct a case that requires no *typename* or *template*, but still yield a variable or template depending on whether a given name `t` is a function parameter pack or not

```
template<typename T> struct A { template<int> static void f(int) { } }; 
template<typename...T> struct A<void(T...,...)> { static const int f = 0; }; 
template<typename> using type = int; 

template<typename T> void f(T t) { A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f<0>(1); }

int main() {
   f(1);   
}
```

The above will refer to the `static const int`, and do a comparison. The following just has `T t` changed to be a pack and make `f` refer to a template, but GCC does not like either

```
template<typename ...T> void f(T ...t) { A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f<0>(1); }

int main() {
   f(1, 2, 3);   
}
```

GCC complains for the first

```
main.cpp:5:68: error: incomplete type 'A<void(type<decltype (t)>, ...)>' used in nested name specifier
 template<typename T> void f(T t) { A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f<0>(1); }
```

And for the second

```
 main.cpp:5:74: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'
  template<typename ...T> void f(T ...t) { A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f<0>(1); }
```

I have multiple questions

- Does the above code work according to the language, or is there an error?
- Since Clang accepts both variants but GCC rejects, I wanted to ask what compiler is correct?
- If I remove the body of the primary template, then for the `f(1, 2, 3)` case, Clang complains

  ```
  main.cpp:5:42: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'A<void (int)>'
  ```

  Please note that it says `A<void (int) >`, while I would expected `A<void (int, int, int)>`. How does this behavior occur? Is this a bug in my code - i.e is it illformed, or is it a bug in Clang? I seem to remember a defect report about the order of expansion vs the substitution of alias template, is that relevant and does it render my code ill-formed?

Comment: For me `void(T...,...)` looks like `T...` is in non deduce context but I'm not sure how compiler should react...

Comment: @W.F. i have seen this in "is_function" traits implementations to detect functions with that pattern. I would be surprised if that would not deduce `T` because then I'm not sure how `is_function` should detect them.

Comment: Didn't know I need to have a look there

Comment: Why would this not require `template` between `::` and `f` in the case where `f` is a `template`?

Comment: @Yakk I was in the impression that `type<dependent-type>` is not dependent if it's `template<typename> using type = int;`, but I could be wrong. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1390 . When asking this question, I forgot about that DR I made long ago, but now I see that actually, it has not been resolved yet. The committee only *clarified that they want it* to be non-dependent. Apart from that, however, is anything else wrong with my snippet?

Comment: @Yakk I guess I should have avoided the alias template and do it with `decltype(sizeof(decltype(t)*))...` which seems not to be type dependent, but looks uglier :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb So, you think you found a way to get at the number of elements in a parameter pack without being "type dependent"?  If so, that looks like a flaw in the standard.  Because practically types and templates resulting from even the number of elements should be "type dependent" (any type depending on any pack expansion should be dependent)

Comment: @Yakk oh gosh, you are right! I think that expansion *actually* makes the function type dependent. That's a great insight. Please provide it as an answer and I will accept, since that's a killer-argument all the way through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding a parameter pack either should, or does, make an expression type dependent.  Regardless of whether the things expanded are type dependent.

If it did not, there would be a gaping hole in the type dependency rules of C++ and it would be a defect in the standard.

So `A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f` when `t` is a pack, no matter what tricks you pull in the `void(` here `)` parts to unpack the `t`, should be a dependent type, and `template` is required before the `f` if it is a `template`.

In the case where `t` is not a pack, it is *intended* that `type<decltype(t)>` not be dependent (See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1390), but the standard may or may not agree at this point (I think not?)

If compilers did "what the committee intended", then when `t` is not a pack:

```
A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f<0>(1)
```

could mean

```
A<void(int...)>::f<0>(1)
```

which is

```
A<void(int, ...)>::f<0>(1)
```

and if `f` is a `template` (your code makes it an `int`, but I think swapping the two should work) this would be fine.  But the standard apparently currently disagrees?

So if http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1390 was implemented, then you could swap your two `A` specializations.  The `void(T...,...)` specialization should have a `template<int> void f(int)`, and the `T` specialization should have a `static const int`.

Now in the case where `A<>` is dependent (on the size of a pack), `::f` is an `int` and does not need `template`.  In the case where `A<>` is not dependent, `::f` is a `template` but does not need disambiguation.

We can replace the `type<decltype(t)>...` with:

```
decltype(sizeof(decltype(t)*))...
```

and `sizeof(decltype(t)*)` is of non-dependent type (it is `std::size_t`), `decltype` gives us a `std::size_t`, and the `...` is treated as a old-school `...` arg.  This means `void(std::size_t...)` becomes a non-dependent type, so `A<void(std::size_t...)>` is not dependent, so `::f` being a template is not a template in a dependent context.

In the case where `t` is a parameter pack with one element

```
decltype(sizeof(decltype(t)*))...
```

becomes

```
std::size_t
```

but *in a dependent context* (one copy per element in `t` pack).  So we get

```
A<void(std::size_t)>::f
```

which is presumed to be a scalar value, so

```
A<void(std::size_t)>::f<0>(1)
```

becomes an expression evaluating to `false`.

(Chain of logic generated in a discussion with Johannes in comments in original question).

Comment: Nice, this even gives a solution that will not require `template` anymore. Should a bugreport be filed against clang for not requiring `template`, and for giving that weird `A<void(int)>` error message?

Comment: The "pack expansion makes it dependent"-DR is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2024

Comment: These are the Q/A for which it is worth to be active on StackOverflow. Thank you for the lesson. +1

Answer (score 3):

Your second case is ill-formed; `A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f<0>(1)` should be

```
A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::template f<0>(1)
//                             ~~~~~~~~~
```

For the first case, both compilers are behaving incorrectly; this was considered sufficiently confusing that [CWG 1520](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1520) was raised to query the correct behavior; the conclusion was that pack expansion should be applied before alias substitution:

> The latter interpretation (a list of specializations) is the correct interpretation; a parameter pack can't be substituted into anything, including an alias template specialization. CWG felt that this is clear enough in the current wording.

This is reminiscent of [CWG 1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558) (alias templates and SFINAE), which was fixed for C++14, but per the above even C++11 compilers are expected to get this correct, so it is disappointing that gcc and clang get it wrong (though in fairness they do behave correctly in simpler cases, including the motivating example in CWG 1520). Note that MSVC had [a similar bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029677) till recently; it is fixed in VS2015.

Your code (only in the first case) is correct; but as a workaround, you could alter your alias template to use and discard its template parameter, fixing your program for both compilers - of course that means that your [CWG 1390](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1390) exploit will cease to be valid:

```
template<typename T> using type = decltype(((int(*)(T*))(0))(0)); // int
```

However, I don't think your CWG 1390 trick can work as presented, since even though the expansion-substitution of `type<decltype(t)>...` is not dependent on the *types* of `t...`, it is dependent on their *number*:

```
template<typename T> struct A { template<int> static void f(int) {} }; 
template<> struct A<void(int, int, int)> { static const int f = 0; };
```

As Yakk points out, it can be made to work if you swap the member function template and data member, since a data member is OK in dependent context.

Comment: Nice trick with the "use and discard", to make both compilers happy with my first case. The need for `template` for the second case makes me sad. If I understand correctly, if http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1390 gets resolved as desired by the commitee-comment, then case 2 will be valid too, without `template`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yep.

Comment: When `t` is a pack `...` with one element, `type<decltype(t)>...` expands to `int`, so the clause reduces to `A<void(int)>::f<0>(1)`.  In `A<void(int)>`, `f` is not a `template`, it is an `int`.  So `template` is *wrong* here, as `f` is not a `template`.  Then `0<0>(0)` is just a sequence of `0<0` (which is false), then `false>(1)` (which is false).  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Yakk the ellipsis is on the other side of the closing angle bracket.

Comment: @ecatmur Typo in comment.  Fixed.  Conclusion unchanged?  Oh blast, it is a `template` here, not an int.  Sigh.  I got the specializations backwards.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb re CWG 1390: consider specializing `template<> struct A<void(int, int, int)>` to see that `template` is required.

Comment: @ecatmur No, it's not. The nested-name-specifier is not dependent in his example. (Or what are you referring to)

Comment: @Columbo it seems dependent; the expected instantiation is `A<void (int, int, int)>` which is dependent on `sizeof...(t)`. So `A<void(type<decltype(t)>...)>::f` is a name dependent on `sizeof...(t)`. No?

Comment: @ecatmur Oh, I completely overlooked the pack example, didn't know what you were referring to. Sorry.